# Colunas "inteligentes" no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Há uma maneira de eu atribuir algo a uma coluna no MySQL afim de quando realizar a consulta eu seleciona-las?

Exemplo prático disso: digamos que eu precise somente mostrar na tela todos os filtros do *site* (filtros são as colunas da tabela), eu posso fazer assim:

```
SELECT filtro_1,filtro_2,filtro_3 FROM filtros
```

Mas se a tabela houver alteração (como adição de um novo filtro, agora o `filtro_4`), esta linha acima não traria os resultados que eu esperava, tendo que refazê-la afim de mostrar também o último filtro (`filtro_4`).

Enfim, como deixar isso "dinâmico"? Como uma marcação das colunas afim de eu seleciona-las pela marcação ao invés pelo nome de coluna, é possível? Caso não, se possível expor alguma sugestão.

Comment: As colunas 'filtro_x' são todas do mesmo tipo?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html veja se ajuda

Comment: Coloque mais informações do seu banco de dados para respondermos a sua resposta por completo. (não sabemos se filtro é string ou não sabemos o que mais tem na tabela filtro) A melhor maneira de fazer isto é colocando os filtros como tabela de relacionamento mesmo. Usar técnicas de normalização no código.

http://imasters.com.br/artigo/7020/banco-de-dados/modelagem-de-dados-final-normalizacao/

Comment: Eu não entendi. Pode postar um DDL (i.e. os `CREATE TABLE`) com um resumo do que está nessa tabela de filtros? O seu dado em si fica em outra tabela, certo? Qual é a diferença de estrutura entre essa outra tabela e a tabela `filtros`?

Comment: Verifica se a tua lógica está correta... Via de regra uma tabela do banco de dados não é algo que deva ser alterado a cada pouco, muito menos programaticamente.

Comment: Tenho a mania de que quando o problema ja não eh mais problema, de esquece-lo, mesmo que terceiros estejam envolvidos. Obrigado por me avisar, esqueci deste compromisso aqui, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apesar de outra resposta dar uma solução, eu acredito que não queria normalizar a tabela para obter o resultado, você apenas quer o facilitador para montar a *query*. Alterar a modelagem por causa disto seria um absurdo.

Nos comentários perguntaram sobre o tipo da colunas. Não sei que soluções mirabolantes estão pensando mas duvido que seja algo legal de usar.

## Dicionário de dados

A única forma que eu vejo de fazer isto é usar um [dicionário de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicion%C3%A1rio_de_dados). Não estou dizendo que deve.

Esta é um técnica antiga que quase todo mundo ignora, por um motivo ou outro. Quase tudo (complexo) que eu faço em banco de dados é em cima de um dicionário de dados, assim me dá facilidade e flexibilidade.

Nele você terá informações sobre como o banco de dados é estruturado. Assim é ele que controla o acesso aos dados. Se você precisar mudar a estrutura do banco, a alteração será feita no dicionário e uma aplicação aplicará as alterações partindo da modificação feita no dicionário.

Entre as inúmeras vantagens ele também pode ser usado para montar suas *queries* da forma como deseja.

Neste caso as colunas teriam uma forma de agrupamento ou de etiquetamento que indique que estas colunas têm um significado específico, quando adicionar uma coluna nova para esta tabela no dicionário de dados com esta *tag*, seu código saberá que para gerar a *query* precisará pegar todas as colunas com a *tag* e imediatamente estará usando-a.

Fazer o sistema de dicionário de dados não é algo simples e se for só para isto também é um absurdo. Mas não há solução simples.

Não vou entrar em mais detalhes sobre o dicionário de dados que não é o foco da pergunta, mas quem quer aplicações superiores deve aprender trabalhar com um.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Em SQL existe o "coringa" que é o `*` que significa *all* ou em português, **tudo**. Ou seja, se você fizer a consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM filtros
```

Você está dizendo:

> Selecione tudo da tabela `filtros`.

Independente de você adicionar ou remover campos, a consulta sempre trará todos os campos da tabela.

Em consultas sem relacionamentos isso é ótimo, mas em casos de relacionamentos com `JOIN` isso deve ter uma precaução:

Imagine as tabela

**Categorias**

```
| ID    | Nome    |
|-------|---------|
| 1     | Eletro  |
| 2     | Sport   |
```

**Produtos**

```
| ID    | Nome    | CatID |
|-------|---------|-------|
| 1     | Ferro   | 1     |
| 2     | Tênis   | 2     |
| 3     | Geladei | 1     |
```

Então a consulta ficaria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM produtos prd
    INNER JOIN categorias cat ON prd.CatID = cat.ID
```

Repare que ambas as tabelas possuem 2 campos iguais `ID` e `Nome`, então qual campo retornará na consulta?

Nesses casos é bom buscar o `*` apenas de uma tabela:

```
SELECT prd.*, cat.nome as categoria_nome 
FROM produtos prd
    INNER JOIN categorias cat ON prd.CatID = cat.ID
```

Assim já temos o ID da categoria no campo `CatID` da tabela de produtos e o nome da categorias com o alias `categoria_nome`.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia criar uma outra tabela para deixar mais dinâmico. Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sua_tabela` (
  `id_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   /*Os outros campos da tabela vai aqui*/
)
```

A segunda tabela seria somente para criar os filtros então seria uma tabela de relacionamento:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filtros` (
   `id_filtro` int(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   `id_tabela` int(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   `filtro` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (id_tabela) REFERENCES sua_tabela(id_tabela) 
)
```

e o select ficaria assim:

```
select filtro from filtros f inner join sua_tabela t on f.id_tabela = t.id_tabela where t.id_tabela = 1 /*O ID do databela qeu você deseja ver os filtros)*/
```

Assim você poderá pesquisar por todos os filtros que estão na tabela X. Esta maneira de colocar vários filtros em uma única tabela não é muito útil pois você terá este seu problema.

Aconcelho você estudar um pouco de normalização, isto ajuda você a criar um banco de dados melhor e mais dinâmico.