# Consultar em todas as tabelas do banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

É possível fazer uma consulta em todas as tabelas que contenham a mesma coluna os seus respectivos valores?

Por exemplo, eu tenho o Banco chamado `SGE`, nele possuo 230 tabelas, sendo que todas essas tabelas possuem a coluna `CodPRF` e eu quero que a *Query* me retorne todos o resultados em que as tabelas possuam a coluna com o valor do `CodPRF` sendo igual a 101.

Pensei em algo parecido com isso (apenas um exemplo pra ver se ajuda melhor no entendimento do problema por parte de vocês):

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ALL_Collums]
FROM   [SGE_TESTE].[dbo].[ALL_Tables]
WHERE  CODPRF = '101'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto aqui resolveu o meu problema.

```
DECLARE @TabNome VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @ColNome VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @Resultado TABLE(TabNome VARCHAR(MAX), ColNome VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE Colunas CURSOR FOR

--Busca todas as colunas de todas as tabelas

SELECT COL.Name, TAB.Name
FROM SYS.Columns COL
  INNER JOIN SYS.Tables TAB ON TAB.Object_Id = COL.Object_Id
  INNER JOIN SYS.Types TYP ON COL.System_Type_Id = TYP.System_Type_Id
WHERE TYP.Name = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                        /*-–filtra o tipo de dado que você procura para
                        --evitar a procura de uma string em um inteiro*/

ORDER BY TAB.Name
OPEN Colunas

FETCH NEXT FROM Colunas INTO @ColNome, @TabNome

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

      EXEC('Select * From ' + @TabNome + ' Where ' + @ColNome + ' Like ''%e5459567-54f6-4792-a3dc-51d5c29a48a0%''') /*–- caso encontre, salva a tabela e a coluna*/

    IF @@RowCount > 0 /*–- caso encontre, salva a tabela e a coluna*/

      BEGIN

            INSERT INTO @Resultado VALUES(@TabNome,@ColNome)

    END



      FETCH NEXT FROM Colunas INTO @ColNome, @TabNome

END

CLOSE Colunas

DEALLOCATE Colunas



SELECT * FROM @Resultado /*–- lista todas as tabelas e suas colunas que*/
```

Fonte: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/3ce127cd-c153-4457-93a7-f32506dfcaf7/preciso-encontrar-um-registro-sem-saber-a-qual-tabela-pertence?forum=520

Answer (score 1):

Diretamente não tem, até porque quando isto é necessário é porque tem algo errado na modelagem do banco de dados.

É possível criar um *script* que leia os metadados do banco de dados ([`information_schema`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) pegue as tabelas que tem esta coluna e gere a *query* que faça em todas tabelas. Só vale a pena se for muitas tabelas. E pode dar um falso positivo dependendo da (in)consistência de nomes usados.

Falo um pouco sobre isto em [Colunas "inteligentes" no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65574/101).